# Convert Python code to PHP but keep it "nice, clean and optimized"

Tags: php, python

A friend of mine told me: "look at this code and try to do it in PHP as easy, concise, and clear".

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
print 'Choose', ', '.join(colors[:-1]), 'or', colors[-1]
```

Is it possible? Do you have any "compact but readable" Php code for this?

(BTW I ask it here because this question doesn't fit codereview, and doesn't fit codegolf).

Comment: I guess you friend was just being sarcastic :-)

Comment: I think your friend told you to do this because s/he knows it's impossible. Not really the best example to prove Python's superiority, but ok.

Comment: Any answer to this is going to be subjective, so this question isn't very constructive.  (But we all know Python will produce nicer code.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the PHP version will always be inferior to the python version since PHP lacks a proper slice operator and since there is only one array type you cannot nicely select the last element using `-1` since that could actually be a valid key.

```
$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');
echo 'Choose ' . implode(', ', array_slice($colors, 0, -1)) . ' or ' . end($colors);
```

Comment: How about the normal definition, let's say the one you get when googling "inferior definition": "Lower in rank, status, or quality"

Comment: Usually inferior in programming means: more bugridden, cannot accomplish the same task etc. That shouldn't be it. The only point for which python will excell in this task in compactness.

Comment: Readability, too. At least I consider a slicing operator much more comfortable than a function that is not even a member function.

Comment: @ThiefMaster while you are correct, this is more of a OOP vs procedural thing and not really PHP's fault.

Comment: Usually true, but PHP is a crude mix of both paradigms.

Comment: Also note that my first comments was on the much shorter version of the post, which only said "the PHP version will always be inferior" without expanding on why the PHP version would be inferior. Current post gives good reasons

Comment: Yeah, I sometimes post a rather short answer and then improve it quickly (*cough* enlightened *cough*)

Answer (score 3):

```
function english_list($items, $conj) {
    $tail = $conj . array_pop($items);
    return implode(', ', $items) . $tail;
}

$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');
echo "Choose ", english_list($colors, " or "), "\n";
```

Not quite as concise, but quite as readable to someone who doesn't know the language.  Maybe even *more* so.  Not being a Python user, i find myself unsure of what `colors[:-1]` means.  (For example, even if i guess that it's a slice....what does it include?)  Or even `colors[-1]`, for that matter -- that's flat-out invalid in most languages, and doesn't do what a Python wonk might think it does in most of the others.

On the other hand, someone who doesn't know PHP (but does know C, C++, Java, JS, Perl, Ruby...or even Python) would still find this readable.  Sure, they might not know what `array_pop` and `implode` do, but they can *very* easily find that out.  Try googling for either of them; the PHP manual -- specifically for the respective function, no less! -- is the first result.  Now try `:`.  :)  (OK, let's be fair: "python array colon operator".)  The first result contains the answer, but you have to dig it out from pretty much everything you did or didn't want to know about arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Python is known for it's incredible compactness, most other languages are much more verbose.

A PHP equivalent of this code uses much more lines/statements (note that this uses syntax introduced in 5.4):

```
$colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
echo 'Choose'
    . implode(', ', array_slice($colors, 0, count($colors)-1))
    . ' or '
    . $colors[count($colors)-1];
```

Ofcourse the newlines before the `.`'s are only added for readability and not neccesary

Comment: Uhh, yes it will: "As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []." (http://php.net/array)